# mongodb in event comments add user to like array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am trying to add user to likes array, currently im not able to since, i can't find the way on how to fetch event comments, findone fails, and im getting catch error function using findone (on event.comments), tried mapping, but since the schema looks like that (see below) im a bit confused.

Event Model

```
  creator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  comments: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      likes: [
        {
          user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My current function:

```
  commentLike: async (req, res) => {
    Events.findById(req.params.idas)
      .then((event) => {
        event.comments.findById(req.params.commentID) //this fails maybe since its not schema model anymore?
          .then((comment) => {
            if (comment.likes.filter((like) => { return like.user.toString() === req.params.id; }).length > 0) {
              return res.status(400).json({ alreadyliked: 'already liked' });
            }
            event.comment.likes.unshift({ user: req.params.id });
            return event.save().then((resevent) => { return res.json(resevent); });
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(404).json({ nopostfound: 'No commnet found' });
      });
  }
```

Im passing three params
id- which is user id
idas - which is event id
commentID - comment id

Comment: You can use `findoneandupdate` instead of doing all these

Comment: Could you please provide more context about that? I saw documentation but it's still unclear for me

Comment: What is your mongodb and mongoose version?

Comment: mongo: 3.4.5, mongoose: 4.11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Events.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.idas, comments: { $elemMatch: { user: req.params.commentID } } },
  { $push: { "comments.$.likes": { user: req.params.id } } }
)
```

Comment: $elemMatch: { user: req.params.commentID} should it be_id instead of user? since we seaching for comment? tried changing it but nothing...

Comment: enabled mongoose logger, the function doesnt fire,  (findoneandupdate)

Comment: And its working! had to call callback function, thanks!

Comment: Also, would like to ask, now i can add as much likes as I want (from one user), what would be proper check in this function, to prevent user to add more likes?

Comment: You can use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` in above query

Comment: That sounds like corrent, since $addToSet doesnt add value to set if it exists, but in my case it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't know, the syntax is the same as your's just changed push to addToSet.
Maybe since im adding object, instead of single value?

Comment: If your array contains object like this `{ user: req.params.id }` then sure it will not add more element with the same object(`{ user: req.params.id }`)

Comment: likes array contais objects like this:
{
  "user" : ObjectId("5b53442c1f09f525441dac31"), 
  _id" : ObjectId("5b54a5263e65324504035eac")  }

So since _id is always different thats the issue why it adds?

Comment: yes now if you will add more `{ $addToSet : { "comments.$.likes": { user:  ObjectId("5b53442c1f09f525441dac31") } } }` then with `$addToSet` you cannot add with this user again

Comment: But im using syntax like this, and it adds objects to array, even if params.id are the same
`{ $addToSet : { "comments.$.likes": { user: req.params.id } } }`